# Angular Routing Issue 'Cannot match any routes'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I just set up a new Angular project and added two Component Routes in my AppRouting Module.

I get the following error when I try to access a route:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cr-calculator'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'cr-calculator'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4396)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:4360)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:29)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at MapSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at MapSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41632)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

And also the router-outlet doesn't work for me for some reason, it just shows blank even if I have some content in my Route Components.

This is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { CrCalculatorPageComponent } from './../pages/cr-calculator-page/cr-calculator-page.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './../pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    data: {
      linkName: 'Home',
      showInMenu: true,
      animation: 'HomePage'
    },
    component: HomePageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'cr-calculator',
    data: {
      linkName: 'CR Calculator',
      showInMenu: true,
      animation: 'CrCalculator'
    },
    component: CrCalculatorPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

... and this is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomePageComponent } from './pages/home-page/home-page.component';
import { CrCalculatorPageComponent } from './pages/cr-calculator-page/cr-calculator-page.component';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    CrCalculatorPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LocationStrategy,
      useClass: HashLocationStrategy
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have multi-checked my code and not found anything. I have also checked out some answered Questions here already but nothing helped me solving my issue.

Thanks in advance and please tell me if you need some more code to review the issue.

// EDIT

HTML-Code with routerLink Statements:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let link of links">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngIf="link.data.showInMenu" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="link.path">{{link.data.linkName}}</a>
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

'links' is basically the routes Object-Array from the app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Please also show how you did the link, eg. manually, or `[routerLink]`.

Comment: tell your routerlink or navigate statement.

Comment: Added in main post

Answer (score 0):

The way you define the `[routerLink]`, the URL ends up something like `cr-calculator`. That is a relative URL, because it doesn't start with `/`. Those don't work if you are not on a top level route. Add a `/` in front of the top level routes, whenever you are specifying the links in your `nav`.

Comment: I changed it to `[routerLink]="'/' + link.path"` but it still does not work

Comment: What ends up in `href` of the `<a>`? And what is the error?

Comment: I have no `href` attribute in my `<a>`, since I'm pretty sure you don't need to do it if you use the `routerLink` (Works fine in other angular project). And the error is in the first block of code in the main post.

Comment: Yes, but the `routerLink` is an angular thing, it is transformed to a vanilla `<a>`. Can you show what it looks like when rendered by angular?

Comment: This is the rendered `<a>`: `<a _ngcontent-yfd-c20="" class="nav-link" ng-reflect-router-link="/cr-calculator" href="#/cr-calculator">CR Calculator</a>`
Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it's nothing wrong with the HTML code because even if I try to access the router page about the URL-bar of the browser - `baseurl/#/cr-calculator` it throws me that error.

Comment: Aha, the `HashLocationStrategy`, I missed that. So the link generated by the `[routerLink]` contains the hash, but the routes in your route file specifies non-hash routes. Do you really need hash-routes? Or did it just end up there accidentally? Try removing that provider completely.

Comment: I fixed it now - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. You all could not know that because when I created the project I added the `App Routing` tag in the command line which automatically generated a AppRouting Module and imported that in my `app.module.ts`. So the error was that I had two AppRouting Modules and I've added my routes in the custom AppRouting but in the `app.module.ts` the Blank App Routing module was linked.